# How to dry paddling gloves

Tags: maintenance, kayaks, water-sports, gloves, paddling

I currently use [MEC Humboldt](http://www.mec.ca/product/5023-626/mec-humboldt-sq-3mm-gloves-unisex/?q=humboldt) paddling gloves for cycling in warm/cool - windy/wet weather as they offer better protection than my thin runnning gloves and are not as hot as my winter gloves.  My issue is when I wear them the second or third day in a row they are still wet on the inside with my perspiration.

1. Is it safe to throw them in the dryer on low heat?
2. If actually used for paddling out in the woods how would you dry them?

EDIT: Can a Silica Gel packet from a shoe box be placed inside the glove to draw out moisture?

Comment: I personally would stuff them with newspaper and/or "prop" them open so that plenty of air gets in there.

Comment: The answers to this will depend on what materials they're made of?

Comment: @Liam they are 3mm Neoprene.

Comment: Related: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/9155/3143

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1.) I would be hesitant to advise you to put them in the dryer. I've never tried or experienced it myself, and my evidence is *completely anecdotal*, but I've heard that the neoprene has the potential to turn brittle if exposed to forced heating.

2.) The two main things to consider when drying out gloves like this (as well as other things like boots, socks, etc) is this:

1. **Absorption** - Try to absorb as much water as possible by stuffing them with old newspaper or dry towels.
2. **Ventilation/Circulation** - You want warm (but not hot), dry air to be able to reach the wet surfaces of the gloves. I've turned mine inside out and they seemed to dry faster, but it depends on how rigid and easily inside-out-able your gloves are. If you can prop them up, get them next to a warm air vent if you've got one.

Another tip (although this wasn't asked in the question) is to keep the smell from neoprene things like this (they often start to smell pretty bad if sweat is allowed to sit in them for too long) is to dry them out thoroughly every time. If you've sweated pretty heavily in them, gently rinse them with cool water and *possibly mild soap depending on the material* and then let them dry. This will prolong the life of your gear and make them not stink like a sock.

EDIT: To answer the addition to your question: I think silica gel could certainly help, and I've got a friend who has used it successfully on hiking boots, but it definitely took a lot longer than the absorption/air drying method.

Comment: Ya they're starting to smell..I'm going to have to wash them well and stuff them with something to absorb the moisture going forward.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I've learned a lot about cleaning stinky stuff having played hockey for years :)

Also, I've edited my original answer to expand on your additional question.