# Is nyloprene less smelly than neoprene?

Tags: water-sports, water-shoes

Because I had a major issue with [reeky water shoes](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/9155/de-stinking-my-water-shoes), I am considering getting different water shoes. I came across [some](http://stohlquist.com/apparel/footwear-gloves/bodhi-watershoe.html) that are nyloprene instead of neoprene. They are not as warm, but in a lot of situations I don't need warm. Say hiking a trail that crosses a river multiple times. Or portaging when I want to get out into the water, wade ashore, portage, and then wade into the water as part of getting back in the boat.

However, if despite being a different material and labelled as quick-dry, they still smell, then I will have gained nothing by getting these shoes. I can't find any claims that they are less smelly. Are they?

Answer (score 2):

Without further information on the actual fabric makeup of the nyloprene being used by [stohlquist](http://stohlquist.com/) it is going to be extremely difficult to properly answer this.

This reason for this is because different companies are making `nyloprene` in different manners.

As I am sure you know `nyloprene` is a multi-layer fabric of `neoprene` and other fabrics, including but not limited to spandex, nylon, and even leather.

You state you *can't find any claims that they are less smelly* and it is highly unlikely that you will unless stohlquist is willing to disclose the fabric makeup they are using.